# Route on Laravel is wrong

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I can't to do this route works...

My Controller:

```
public function profissionais(Request $request, $id){
    $profissionais = Vinculo::where('unidade_id', '=', $id)->get();
    $profissionais = $id;
    return view('relatorios.profissionais', compact('profissionais'));
}
```

My Form:

```
<form method="GET" action="{{route('relatorios.profissionais', 'id')}}">
    <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="id" required>
        @foreach($unidades as $unidade)
            <option value="{{$unidade->id}}">{{$unidade->descricao}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Listar</button>
    </span>
</form>
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('/relatorios/profissionais/{id}', 'RelatorioController@profissionais')->name('relatorios.profissionais');
```

I like my route like this: `/relatorios/profissionais/4` (4 is the ID) and the number 4 will the `$id` variable.

But the uri is like: `relatorios/profissionais/id?id=4`

Any help?

Comment: @Rafee is a view `public/views/relatorios/profissionais.blade.php`

Comment: you need to pass the right arguments in form action="{{route('relatorios.profissionais', 4)}}"

Comment: i see there is select element, you either change the action url on change and dont pass that select element

Comment: @Rafee the number 4 is a example of number generated by my form on input select.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/N4r8Ecj4 I believe you need this to achieve what you are doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter of the route helper should be the value of the parameter, not the key.

```
{{route('relatorios.profissionais', 4)}}
```

Now, because you're setting this value from the form, you either need to use the request input instead of a route parameter or use javascript to modify the form action using a listener on the change event of your select element.

The reason you have `/id` is because of `'id'` being the 2nd argument.  The reason you have `?id=4` is because it is a form value, not a route parameter.

---

You're also overwriting `$profissionais` immediately after retrieving the collection

```
    $profissionais = $id;
```

Comment: The number 4 is only a example, I like to get the value from the form

Comment: Right, well either use `$request->id` instead of a route parameter or use a javascript listener to customize the url on changes.

Comment: and the form `<form method="GET" action="{{route('relatorios.profissionais', 'id')}}">` is correct?

Comment: If you want to replace id with the javascript listener, otherwise no.  Edit: Actually, no, I wouldn't even do that because that would only work for the first change event.

Comment: Understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like:

```
Route::get('/relatorios/profissionais/{id?}', 'RelatorioController@profissionais')->name('relatorios.profissionais');
```